# Using regex to find something between string and switch them

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following pattern ##/##/#### within a string "##/##/#### ##:## ## ###".  As an example "11/22/3333 11:22 AM EST" would like to switch the 11 and 22 to result in 22/11/3333.  I am new to understanding regex. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to create a date object from the string, you can do `Date.strptime("11/22/3333 11:22 AM EST", '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M %p %Z')`

Comment: @Santosh This is also an excellent answer... Just flipping the `%m`, `%d`... will work...Easy to read also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do with:

```
'11/22/3333'.gsub(%r{(.*)/(.*)/(.*)}, '\2/\1/\3')
```

Comment: @xdazz I should have mentioned there is more to the string, I will update the question. the entire string is "##/##/#### ##:## ## ###" I would still just like to switch the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 input_string="11/22/3333"
 output_array=input_string.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/)
 p "#{output_array[2]}/#{output_array[1]#{output_array[3]}}"
```